# How to execute a defined function with different arguments parallel

Tags: python, function, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I have a function with multiple arguments. I need is a code block that will execute my function parallel with 3 different sets of arguments then hold there till all the processes are done before running my other code block.

I tried this but the result isn't the one I need.

```
import multiprocessing
from itertools import product

bs = []
def a(i):
    for x in range(i):
        print(i)
        b = x + 1
        bs.append(b)
    return bs

if __name__ == '__main__':
    i = range(4)
    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=3) as pool:
        result = pool.starmap(a, product(i))
    print(result)
```

The result:

```
1
2
2
3
3
3
[[], [1], [1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3]]
```

I have read thread where guys used `Process` from `multiprocessing`, which have `.join()` but I don't understand enough to write codes base on them.

**Edit:**

I also tried this and get an error:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

bs = []
def a(i):
    for x in range(i):
        print(i)
        b = x + 1
        bs.append(b)
    return bs

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = Process(target=a(2))
    p1.start()
    p2 = Process(target=a(3))
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

The result:

```
2
2
3
3
3
Process Process-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "E:\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
Process Process-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "E:\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Since multiprocessing is a bit complicated, can you help me to solve this?.
Thank you.

Comment: what is wrong with the result? what are you trying to do that the result isn't?

Comment: @J'e: The result I'm looking for would look like this ```[ [1], [1,2], [1,2,3], [1,2,3,4] ]```

Comment: Notice the dangling comma after `args=('bob',)` https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#the-process-class  Don't call your function, let multiprocessing call it